# How do I define a function to split a string into separate lines?

Tags: python, function, methods, split, sentence

Say, the string looks like:

> I like pie. You like apples. We like oranges.

How would I define a function, called `format_poem()` that would essentially take any input with a paragraph like the one above and give us each sentence in a separate line?

I'm sure it lies in the period after each sentence but being a noob, I can't wrap my head around it. Does this also use the `.split()` method?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the periods with the character for a new line (which is almost universally `\n`) using `.replace()`

```
def format_poem(paragraph):
    return paragraph.replace('. ','\n')
```

Comment: So I did this:

    def format_poem(poem):
      return poem.replace(".","\n")

And then I call on the function and pass through the long paragraph and what it returns is just all the periods being replaced by the string "\n" haha

Edit: how I format the code in this reply haha. Sorry, noob to this site

Comment: How are you viewing the output? `\n` is a new line character, so if printed or written to a file, it should generally result in the output being spread across multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: `split` will do what you need.

```
str = "I like pie. You like apples. We like oranges."

def format_poem(inStr):
     t = inStr.split(". ")
     return t

for el in format_poem(str):
    print(el)
```

Output:

```
I like pie
You like apples
We like oranges.
```

Alternatively, you can print the lines inside the function just moving the for-loop inside the function:

```
I like pie. You like apples. We like oranges.

def format_poem(inStr):
     t = inStr.split(". ")
     for el in t:
         print(el)
```

---

In order to preserve the period at the end of the sentences, like in the original string, you need to use `replace()` method, searching `". "` and replacing with `".\n"`. Please note how this method doesn't modify the original string:

```
#Perform replacement
str2 = str1.replace(". ", '.\n')
#Print the original string
print(str1)
#Print new string, result of the replacement
print(str2)
```

The new output is:

```
#The original string
I like pie. You like apples. We like oranges.
#The newly assigned string    
I like pie.
You like apples.
We like oranges.
```

Comment: What if I wanted the function to have done all that for me, including the for loop?

Comment: @codingnoob You want the print inside the function? Well.. move the for inside it..

Comment: Hi! Sorry, just got back to it. So I utilized your second function with the for-loop in it. It looks better with the sentences actually on separate lines! But, if I were to ask for nitpicking purposes, how would I keep the period at the end of the sentences, being that it takes that out? Also, I noticed that after the first sentence in the output, the other three are indented. Any way to prevent the other three sentences from indenting? Thanks for your guidance through this!

Comment: Hey again, disregard the part about the indents being weird in my previous reply. It was just cause I forgot to include the space after the period in the split method~

Comment: @CodingNoob I've added a further section